# How do I search for a specific value in a generic List in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, generics

```
class MyGenericClass<T> where T : ICompareable
{
  T[] data;

  public AddData(T[] values)
  {
     data = values;
  }
}
```

In my mainForm, I create 3 random numbers, and add them as values: `1 3 3`, resulting in:

```
T[] data :  [0]1 
            [1]3 
            [2]3
```

I want to be able to search for a specific value and have the number of times that value is present in the array returned to me.

How do I do that in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
   public class MyGenericClass<T> where T : IComparable 
   {
    T[] Data;

    public void AddData(T[] values) 
    {
        Data = values;

        var list = Data.ToList();
        object compareWith = new object();
        compareWith = 3;


        int count = list.Where(a=>a.CompareTo(compareWith) == 0).Count();

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 8):

```
return data.Count(t => t.CompareTo(valueToSearchFor) == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be easily done since you have your type parameter implement IComparable. all you need is this:

```
internal class MyGenericClass<T> where T : IComparable
{
    private T[] data;

    public void AddData(T[] values)
    {
        data = values;
    }
    public int FindValue<T>(T value)
    {
        return data.Count(v => v.CompareTo(value) == 0);
    }
}
```

and the call would be something like:

```
var myClass = new MyGenericClass<int>();
myClass.AddData(new[] {1,2,3,1});
var count = myClass.FindValue(1);
```

and that should work (worked for me ;) )

Hope this helps :)